# SOCKS proxy to SSH server behind HTTP proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, sshd, socks5

I set up a SOCKS proxy at port 9090 to computer B elsewhere:

```
ssh -D localhost:9090 user@B
```

and configured it in my local Google Chrome browser.
However, computer B is behind an HTTP proxy, so HTTP requests originating locally get to computer B through the SOCKS proxy but can't be addressed (terminal running ssh -D localhost:9090 user@B shows "open failed: connect failed: No route to host" when such a request is made).

I have tried:

1. setting up BOTH remote HTTP proxy (behind which computer B is) and SOCKS proxy in Google Chrome,
2. running ssh -D localhost:9090 user@B with environment variable http_proxy properly set,
3. adding http_proxy=_proxy_address_ to the user's .bashrc on computer B;

but none worked.

Anyone knows how to configure the SOCKS proxy so as to take into account the HTTP proxy behind which computer B is? Any method which does not involve changing SSHD or global configuration at the server would be prefered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do a lot better to "forward" the remote network's proxy server over SSH rather than using the built-in SOCKS server (which just expects a bare gateway-addressable network at the other end).

```
ssh -L 8080:internal_ip_of_proxy:8080 user@ssh_server
```

This exposes the proxy server locally, allowing you to set your browser's proxy settings to `localhost:8080` and that will tunnel over SSH to the remote proxy.

And you can apply this to any remote service. You could, for example, tunnel Imgur from your server (in effect a single-host proxy):

```
ssh -L 8080:imgur.com:80 user@ssh_host
```

And on a local terminal:

```
curl --header 'Host: imgur.com' localhost:8080
```

The Host header is required otherwise `curl` will request a non-existent `localhost` site. You could also work around that by adding a line in `/etc/hosts`, resolving `imgur.com` to `127.0.0.1`... But I'm getting off-topic, you don't need any of this for your purposes.

Comment: I tried it in some other way but not succeeded. It works like a charm!