# How to connect/forward HTTP proxy through ssh?

Tags: ssh, proxy

I have a PC `A` behind proxy server `S`. `A` can use the internet with browser + proxy login, or terminal + export http command.

Now I have another PC `B` that's connected to `A`. How can I access `A`'s internet from another PC `B`, provided I can ssh between `A` and `B`?

Edit:
In [this question (469582)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469582/how-do-i-set-up-a-local-socks-proxy-that-tunnels-traffic-through-ssh), what I understand is that `the PC` (`A`) is directly connected to internet. In my case, however, `A` has to login to another proxy server `S` before it can use internet. Can I make a tunnel for this?

Comment: @muru [SOCKS proxy to SSH server behind HTTP proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589851/socks-proxy-to-ssh-server-behind-http-proxy) does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Open a socks proxy from `B`:

```
ssh -D 1080 -f -q -N user@A
```

Tell your browser to use it:

[image]